# Most efficient way to iterate through Lists and Forward List

Tags: c++

In the one of the question on the studio for my class, it asks to create iterators for 2 different object types (list, forwardlist) that are pointing 2 past the beginning of each type in the MOST EFFICIENT MANNER.  I'm not sure what constitutes the most efficient manner.
Obviously I could use a for loop to move the iterator twice, but I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.  I also tried using the next function, but it did not appear to work.  Is there a better way than the for loop?

```
auto it = list.begin()
for (int i = 0; i< 2; i++){
 ++iterator;
}
```

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I did not get what you are asking...

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Most of the confusion is coming from the 'that are pointing 2 past the beginning of each type' part.

Comment: *"but it did not appear to work"* - well, the code you've posted creates `it` but increments `iterator`, but when asking a question like this you should post your actual code - ideally a small compilable program, any compiler/linker error message or output, and what you expected or don't understand about the behaviour.  Anyway, simply `++++it;` will do the job - no loop required.  There's no great mystery here.  Unless you have a random access container like a `vector`, you simply have to follow the pointers from node to node, which is what incrementing the iterator returned by `begin()` does.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency - for this context - can mean efficient use of memory, cpu cycles, non-duplication of efforts, and more.

The most important aspect of your exercise is to have some kind of understanding of the code that will be used. That does not just mean the code you write, but the code contained in the libraries you use. Once you are comfortable with all of the code in use, then you can begin to analyze it.

Some ideas:

- read about the iterator and collection libraries that you use for lists. Also read about how they perform 'begin()' and 'next()'. If there are no articles on this, you may have to have a look at the source code.
- can the int loop index be swapped for a byte? (splitting hairs).